# Product of countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebras vs $\sigma$-algebra of product

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=Y$ uncountable, and let $A = B$ be the $\sigma$ algebra of countable-cocountable subsets of $X, Y$ respectively. Let $C$ be the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$.

Is $C = \sigma (A \times B)$?

$\subseteq$ is obvious, but I am not sure about the other direction. I know that in general the two do not have to be equal, so I am trying to find a counterexample i.e find an element in $C$ which is not in $\sigma(A \times B)$. Perhaps AC is involved, which makes it tricky? I am not sure.

Also, is it true that $\sigma(A \times B) = A \times B?$ This may help simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said it is obvious that  $C \subseteq \sigma (A \times B)$.

However the inclusion in the other direction is not true. Here is a simple counter-example:

Let $X=Y=[0,1]$ and let $A = B$ be the $\sigma$ algebra of countable-cocountable subsets of $X, Y$ respectively. Let $C$ be the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$.
Let $S = \{\frac{1}{2}\} \times [0,1]$. It is immediate that $S \in \sigma(A \times B)$, but $S \notin C$.

**Remark**: The example above is actually a general example. In fact:

Let $X=Y$ uncountable, and let $A = B$ be the $\sigma$ algebra of countable-cocountable subsets of $X, Y$ respectively. Let $C$ be the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$.

Let us choose $a \in X$. Let $S = \{a \} \times Y$. It is immediate that $S \in \sigma(A \times B)$, but $S \notin C$.

Comment: Is there a counterexample with general $X$?

Comment: @John , Yes. Please see the Remark I have added to my answer.